# GraphQL problem with having both dataFetcher and typeResolver

Tags: kotlin, graphql, graphql-java

I am currently working on a Kotlin, Reactor, GraphQL, MongoDB Project.

There seems to be a problem with my graphql building schema but I can't figure it out.

I have an interface `Foo`

```
interface Foo {
    id: ID
    field1: String
    field2: String
}
```

And I have another interface `Bar`

```
interface Bar{
    id: ID
    field1: String
    field2: String
```

Both are interfaces, so I had them type resolved by adding some lines on my `RuntimeWiring`.

```
RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()

    /* Shortend for brevity */

    .type(newTypeWiring("Foo")
        .typeResolver(fooResolvers.fooTypeResolver())
        .dataFetcher("bar", barDataFetchers.getBar())
    .type(newTypeWiring("Bar")
        .typeResolver(barResolvers.barTypeResolver())
    ...
    .build()
```

When I send a query asking for `bar` from `Foo`, It doesn't even get to `barDataFetchers.getBar()`.

Is there something that I'm missing?

### EDIT

After setting my logging level of graphql to DEBUG,

I figured it out that graphql-java is using `graphql.schema.PropertyDataFetcher` to fetch data for `bar`.

This is not what I intended. It should use my own dataFetcher, `barDataFetchers`

Comment: I think your question isn't clear enough. What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Diego, I've updated my question. Please have a look.

I am currently trying to search using my own dataFetcher. But GraphQL forces to use its own propertyDataFetcher.

Thanks